# I am facing a problem in showing an image in my crud table in laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

This is my create function which store Client Logo in database

```
public function create()
{
    $this->pictures->store('pictures');
    $this->clientlogo->store('clientlogo');
    $this->validate();
    mprojectm::create($this->modelData());
    $this->modalFormVisible = false;
    $this->resetVars();
}
```

and here is my table code

```
<td>
    <img src="{{ asset('storage/app/clientlogo/'.$item->clientlogo) }}" alt="coming Soon" width="50" height="60">
</td>
```

this image is stored in Path  `storage/app/clientlogo`

Comment: Create a symlink and you will get the image

Comment: Instead use asset use 'url' like src="{{url('storage/app/clientlogo/'.$item->clientlogo)}}"